# Use returned ID from SCOPE_IDENTITY in new Query

Tags: php, sql-server

Right now, this is what I have:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO COMMENTS VALUES ('$user', '$comment', '$star')"; 
mssql_query($query, $connection);
$commentIDQuery = "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ins_id";
$CI = mssql_query ($commentIDQuery, $connection);
$commentID = mssql_fetch_row($CI);
$idQuery = "SELECT recipeid FROM t_recipe WHERE recipename = '$recipeName'";
$RID = mssql_query($idQuery, $connection);
$recipeID = mssql_fetch_row($RID);  
$rcQuery = "INSERT INTO COMMENT_RECIPE VALUES ('$commentID[0]', '$recipeID[0]')";
    mssql_query($rcQuery, $connection);
```

So how would I get that ins_id?

It adds it to the first table, which is comments, but not the relation table.

Using sql server 2008

Comment: what you have is invalid syntax.

Comment: is the id the primary key?

Comment: Yes, when I use just the first two querys in SSMS it returns back the last generated primary key.

Comment: doh, sql-server ignore me sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this......

```
$query = "DECLARE @NewID INT
          INSERT INTO COMMENTS VALUES ('$user', '$comment', '$star');
          SELECT @NewID  = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
          INSERT INTO COMMENTS_RECIPE VALUES (@NewID, '$recipeid')";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
```

Comment: Still only just going into the first table for some reason, but let me double check my formatting

Comment: Are you sure you have an Identity Column in `Comments` table ?

Comment: If you see the very first line in my code, I have declared a variable `@NewID` of INT datatype, Later I used this variable to store the newly inserted Identity value to this variable and than simply passed the variable in following INSERT statement.

Comment: Its my fault, I never passed the variable to the next page that it needed to get the recipeid